# Elegantly appending a set of strings (.txt file) to another set of strings (.txt also)?

Tags: sql, string, algorithm, text, append

This request might seem slightly ridiculous, unfortunately however, it is direly needed by my small company and because of this I will be awarding the maximum bounty for a good solution.

We have a set of legacy order information stored in a .txt file. In order to import this order information into our new custom database system, we need to, for each row, append on a value from another set.

So, in my .txt file I have :

```
Trans Date,NorthTotal,NorthSoFar,SouthTotal,SouthSoFar,IsNorthWorkingDay,IsSouthWorkingDay
2012-01-01,21,0,21,0,0,0
2012-01-02,21,0,21,0,0,0
2012-01-03,21,1,21,1,1,1
...
```

Now, I have a set of locations in a .txt file also, for which I need to add two columns - city and country. Let's say :

```
City, Country
London,England
Paris,France
```

For each row in my first text file, I need to append on a row of my second text file! So, for my end result, using my sample data above, I wish to have :

```
Trans Date,NorthTotal,NorthSoFar,SouthTotal,SouthSoFar,IsNorthWorkingDay,IsSouthWorkingDay,City,Country
2012-01-01,21,0,21,0,0,0,London,England
2012-01-02,21,0,21,0,0,0,London,England
2012-01-03,21,1,21,1,1,1,London,England
2012-01-01,21,0,21,0,0,0,Paris,France
2012-01-02,21,0,21,0,0,0,Paris,France
2012-01-03,21,1,21,1,1,1,Paris,France
...
```

At the moment my only idea for this is to import both files into an SQL database and write a complicated function to append the two together (hence my tag) - surely someone can save me and think of something that will not take all day though! Please?! Thank you very much.

Edit : I am open to solutions written in all programming languages; but would prefer something which uses DOS or some kind of console/program that can be easily reran!

Comment: Can you interpret both files as CSV? 
That would make merging those files easy using that SheetReferenceFunction build into Excel.

Comment: @CSharpie Yes I can indeed! Can you provide me some information on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using a database and importing these files (which should not be very difficult), then you do not need a "complicated function to append the two together". All you need is a simple cross join like this ... `select t1.*, t2.* from t1, t2`

See for yourself at... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c584/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in C#. You run it like:

```
joinfiles a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

where a.txt is the first file, b.txt the second one, and c.txt the output file that will be created. It generates the output at 100 MB/s on my machine so that is probably fast enough.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace JoinFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 3)
                return;

            string[] file1, file2;

            try
            {

                using (var sr1 = new StreamReader(args[0]))
                using (var sr2 = new StreamReader(args[1]))
                {
                    file1 = sr1.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    file2 = sr2.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                }

                using (var outstream = new StreamWriter(args[2], false, Encoding.Default, 1048576))
                {
                    outstream.WriteLine(file1[0] + "," + file2[0]);

                    for (int i = 1; i < file2.Length; i++)
                        for (int j = 1; j < file1.Length; j++)
                            outstream.WriteLine(file1[j] + "," + file2[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bash script example

```
echo -e 'c1\na\nb' > t1
echo -e 'c2\n1\n2' > t2
while read l1;do
  read -u 3 l2
  echo "$l1,$l2"
done <t1 3<t2
```

see `man bash` / internal function / read

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a WSH script to do this and execute from the command line. Here is a quick hack (works but will certainly need some refining). You'll need to save this as a vbs file and execute on the cli like this... `wscript script.vbs infile1.txt infile2.txt outfile.txt` where script.vbs is your script and infile 1 and 2 are input filenames and outfile.txt is the output file.

```
Set FSO_In1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO_In2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO_Out = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File_Out = FSO_In1.CreateTextFile(Wscript.Arguments.Item(2),2)
Set F1_file = FSO_In1.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0),1)
HeaderWritten = False
Header = F1_File.Readline 'Read the first header line from first file
Do While F1_File.AtEndOfStream = False
   F1_Line = F1_file.Readline
   Set F2_File = FSO_In2.OpenTextFile(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1),1)
   if HeaderWritten = False then
       Header = Header & "," & F2_File.Readline
       File_Out.Writeline(Header)
       HeaderWritten = True
   else
       F2_File.Readline 'Read the first header line from second file and ignore it
   end if
   Do While F2_File.AtEndOfStream = False
       F2_Line = F2_File.Readline
       out = F1_Line & "," & F2_Line
       File_Out.Writeline(out)
   Loop
   F2_File.Close
Loop
F1_File.Close
File_Out.Close
```